# Modifying fs/binfmt_elf.c to fetch a custom-added section content

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, elf

I am trying to modify `fs/binfmt_elf.c` to fetch the content of a new ELF section I have added to my sample C program.

Sample C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
/* Adding my own ELF section*/
char my_custom_section[128][2] __attribute__ ((section (".mysection"))) = { 0 };
 
int main() {
      return 0;
}
```

Here's the output of `readelf -l a.out`:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x4003d0
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000000067c 0x000000000000067c  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000e28 0x0000000000600e28 0x0000000000600e28
                 0x00000000000002f8 0x0000000000000308  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000e50 0x0000000000600e50 0x0000000000600e50
                 0x0000000000000190 0x0000000000000190  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000000005ac 0x00000000004005ac 0x00000000004005ac
                 0x000000000000002c 0x000000000000002c  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     8
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000e28 0x0000000000600e28 0x0000000000600e28
                 0x00000000000001d8 0x00000000000001d8  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .mysection .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got
```

So `.mysection` is assigned to segment 03 of type `LOAD`.

However, going through the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c?v=3.2) of `fs/binfmt.c`, I am unable to understand how exactly can I fetch the content/value of `.mysection`. It seems that `load_elf_binary()` only iterates through program headers and segments, and not section headers or sections.
(which presumably makes sense because it's a loader and hence, views an ELF file as segments and not as sections).

But even when it iterates through the program segments, I don't understand how is it iterating through the sections within a segment.

Basically, I need to fetch the value of my own section `.mysection`, through modifying `fs/binfmt.c`, so that whenever an ELF executable with `.mynewsection` is loaded in my kernel, its value is stored in some variable/CPU registers. Any pointers which can help in doing this job are much appreciated.

EDIT:
My primary goal is to extend the ELF file format into my own custom file format, which I plan to use for a research project on extending the x86 architecture. The executables in that extended architecture need to have a unique identity key used to perform cryptographic operations on its code/data segments. Therefore, a new section in the file could store that key, and the kernel loader can fetch it for further cryptographic processes.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why do you want to do it in kernel? (You could improve `ld-linux.so`)

Comment: I need that custom-section value to act as a unique identity for a binary. You mean, write my own ld script to be used instead of GNU ld? Another possibility is to use my own mapfile, create a new segment and map my custom section to that segment. But that seems like an overkill for the job at hand. What do you think?

Comment: I was suggesting writing your own dynamic loader... (not an `ld` script). But you should explain what is your overall goal. What "unique identity" means to you? Please *edit your question* to improve it (add motivations and explanations about your goal).

Comment: I have edited the question to include my motivation.

Comment: Writing a dynamic loader is one way, but again, could there be any more subtle and simpler way? I mean, all I need to do is to fetch a section's value during program loading.

Comment: A dynamic loader is simpler to do (actually, start with an existing one!) that hacking inside the kernel...

Comment: what would happen if a program is completely statically linked/built? In such a case, when the program will be loaded, will the OS still pass control to ld-linux.so instead of normal entry point of the program? Ideally, I would want my modified ld-linux.so to come into play regardless of the program being statically linked or not.

Answer (score 0):

> But even when it iterates through the program segments, I don't
>   understand how is it iterating through the sections within a segment.

Since `load_elf_binary()` *mmap*s all the `PT_LOAD` segments into memory, and those segments contain all the needed sections (e. g. segment `03` contains sections `.ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .mysection .bss`), there is no need for iterating through the sections.